# Faster bulk inserts in sqlite3?

Tags: c++, sqlite, insert, bulk

I have a file of about 30000 lines of data that I want to load into a sqlite3 database. Is there a faster way than generating insert statements for each line of data?

The data is space-delimited and maps directly to an sqlite3 table. Is there any sort of bulk insert method for adding volume data to a database?

Has anyone devised some deviously wonderful way of doing this if it's not built in?

I should preface this by asking, is there a C++ way to do it from the API?

Comment: very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can also try [tweaking a few parameters](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#modify) to get extra speed out of it. Specifically you probably want `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;`.

Comment: pragma synchronous = OFF is a bad idea - it'll hardly impact performance at all for bulk inserts, and your DB will be corrupted on a power failure.  A much better idea is to wrap your inserts in a transaction.

Comment: Wrapping the INSERTS in a TRANSACTION and using

PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY; 

Will prevent the INSERTs from hitting the disk until the end of the transaction.

Comment: Beware that MEMORY will corrupt db on a power failure

Comment: PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL; will allow many writers at a time, and you could eventually use threads to write the data.
Note that with Write-Ahead Logging activated, the DB is not corrupted after power failure.

Answer (score 64):

- wrap all INSERTs in a transaction, even if there's a single user, it's far faster.
- use prepared statements.

Comment: True for most (all?) SQL databases.

Comment: PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY;

Might be helpful for some people

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511725/transaction-management-in-sqlite3-using-expressjs transaction example for Nodejs dev

Answer (score 46):

You want to use the `.import` command. For example:

```
$ cat demotab.txt
44      92
35      94
43      94
195     49
66      28
135     93
135     91
67      84
135     94

$ echo "create table mytable (col1 int, col2 int);" | sqlite3 foo.sqlite
$ echo ".import demotab.txt mytable"  | sqlite3 foo.sqlite

$ sqlite3 foo.sqlite
-- Loading resources from /Users/ramanujan/.sqliterc
SQLite version 3.6.6.2
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from mytable;
col1    col2
44      92
35      94
43      94
195     49
66      28
135     93
135     91
67      84
135     94
```

Note that this bulk loading command is not SQL but rather a custom feature of SQLite. As such it has a weird syntax because we're passing it via `echo` to the interactive command line interpreter, `sqlite3`.

In PostgreSQL the equivalent is `COPY FROM`:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-copy.html

In MySQL it is `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

One last thing: remember to be careful with the value of `.separator`. That is a very common gotcha when doing bulk inserts.

```
sqlite> .show .separator
     echo: off
  explain: off
  headers: on
     mode: list
nullvalue: ""
   output: stdout
separator: "\t"
    width:
```

You should explicitly set the separator to be a space, tab, or comma before doing `.import`.

Comment: This is great, and very fast. 20 minutes reduced to 3 seconds.

Comment: does this work for tables which have auto increment primary keys? I tried using a NULL in the file for an auto increment column but it throws an error.

Comment: Looking at the code for SQLite's shell.c, .import is just using a prepared statement inside a transaction.

Comment: sqlite has a strange behaviour with \t on command line, you 
must give a REAL tab to the -separator option. On command line, use 
Control-v <TAB> to insert a real TAB.

Answer (score 30):

I've tested some [pragmas](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html) proposed in the answers here:

- `synchronous = OFF`
- `journal_mode = WAL`
- `journal_mode = OFF`
- `locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE`
- `synchronous = OFF` + `locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE` + `journal_mode = OFF`

Here's my numbers for different number of inserts in a transaction:

[image]

Increasing the batch size can give you a real performance boost, while turning off journal, synchronization, acquiring exclusive lock will give an insignificant gain. Points around ~110k show how random background load can affect your database performance.

Also, it worth to mention, that `journal_mode=WAL` is a good alternative to defaults. It gives some gain, but do not reduce reliability.

[C# Code.](https://github.com/astef/benchmark-sqlite3-bulk-insert)

Comment: One thing I noticed in one of my projects is that a batch should be restricted to a single table if at all possible.  If you are inside a transaction and updating table a then table b in a loop, this will run much much slower than looping twice, once for table a then again for table b.

Answer (score 23):

- Increase `PRAGMA cache_size`
  to a much larger number. This will
  increase the number of pages cached
  in memory. NOTE: `cache_size` is a per-connection setting.
- Wrap all inserts into a single transaction rather than one transaction per row.
- Use compiled SQL statements to do the inserts.
- Finally, as already mentioned, if you are willing forgo full ACID compliance, set `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;`.

Comment: `PRAGMA default_cache_size` is now [deprecated](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_default_cache_size)

Comment: `cache_size` can be used instead of the deprecated `default_cache_size`. However, `cache_size` is for a single connection.

Answer (score 14):

> RE: "Is there a faster way that generating insert statements for each line of data?"

First: Cut it down to 2 SQL statements by making use of Sqlite3's [Virtual table API](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_module.html) e.g.

```
create virtual table vtYourDataset using yourModule;
-- Bulk insert
insert into yourTargetTable (x, y, z)
select x, y, z from vtYourDataset;
```

The idea here is that you implement a C interface that reads your source data set and present it to SQlite as a virtual table and then you do a SQL copy from the source to the target table in one go. It sounds harder than it really is and I've measured huge speed improvements this way.

Second: Make use of the other advise provided here i.e. the pragma settings and making use of a transaction.

Third: Perhaps see if you can do away with some of the indexes on the target table. That way sqlite will have less indexes to update for each row inserted

Comment: +1 this one is actually a "c" way to do it from the API (as requested), nice one

Comment: I tried and didn't find any improvements compared to prepared batched insert with a big batch size in a transaction. Loading through a virtual table 5-10% slower, in both in-memory and WAL scenarios, with different page_size, synchronous values.

Answer (score 7):

> There is no way to bulk insert, but
> there is a way to write large chunks
> to memory, then commit them to the
> database.  For the C/C++ API, just do:
>
> sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION",
> NULL, NULL, NULL);
>
> ...(INSERT statements)
>
> sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL);

Assuming db is your database pointer.

Answer (score 6):

A good compromise is to wrap your INSERTS between BEGIN; and END; keyword i.e:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table VALUES ();
INSERT INTO table VALUES ();
...
END;
```

Comment: There's also `INSERT INTO table VALUES (),(),();`

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the size of the data and the amount of RAM available, one of the best performance gains will occur by setting sqlite to use an all-in-memory database rather than writing to disk.

For in-memory databases, pass NULL as the filename argument to `sqlite3_open` and  [make sure that TEMP_STORE is defined appropriately](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store)

(All of the above text is excerpted from my own answer to a [separate sqlite-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136175/fastest-small-datastore-on-windows#136714))

Comment: The link points to an incomplete document.  There is less information than one would hope for,

Answer (score 4):

I found this to be a good mix for an one shot long import.

```
.echo ON

.read create_table_without_pk.sql

PRAGMA cache_size = 400000; PRAGMA synchronous = OFF; PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF; PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE; PRAGMA count_changes = OFF; PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY; PRAGMA auto_vacuum = NONE;

.separator "\t" .import a_tab_seprated_table.txt mytable

BEGIN; .read add_indexes.sql COMMIT;

.exit
```

source: http://erictheturtle.blogspot.be/2009/05/fastest-bulk-import-into-sqlite.html

some additional info: http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/

Answer (score 1):

If you are just inserting once, I may have a dirty trick for you.

The idea is simple, first inserting into a memory database, then backup and finally restore to your original database file.

I wrote the detailed steps at [my blog](http://notes.theorbis.net/2009/12/fast-batch-insert-to-sqlite-database.html). :)

Comment: You blog is closed from viewer, but I have serious doubts about sustainability of this method. The problem is that modern SSD are not that much slower then RAM. I tried to optimize `page_size` for both in-memory and WAL scenarios, and then compared them. I got 35% improvement for a 200MB db. Not bad, but I don't see how it can be enough to justify the backup and restore. I think it should be much slower in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I do a bulk insert with this method:

```
colnames = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'] 
nrcols = len(colnames) 
qmarks = ",".join(["?" for i in range(nrcols)]) 
stmt = "INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(" + qmarks + ")" 
vals = [[val11, val12, val13], [val21, val22, val23], ..., [valn1, valn2, valn3]] 
conn.executemany(stmt, vals)

colnames must be in the order of the column names in the table 
vals is a list of db rows
each row must have the same length, and
contain the values in the correct order 
Note that we use executemany, not execute
```