# How to speed up creating an SQL table? RSQLite, 20 billion rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, rsqlite, bigdata

I'm using SQLite with R (the package `RSQLite`). The following after importing `rSQLite`, I'm trying to pipe 500 GB of data into an SQL table with the standard following command:

```
CREATE TABLE name (
 field1 INTEGER,
 field2 VARCHAR,
 field3 INTEGER,
 field4 INTEGER,
 field5 VARCHAR,
 );
```

However, this takes approximately 3 weeks to complete. How does one speed this up? Are other options commonly used?

I am trying to perform around 100 queries under one second on 20 billion rows, 5 columns. I am not using multiple commodity machines, but rather a single HPC server with 200 threads and 1 TB RAM. What would be the correct approach?

Comment: Why not load all the data in memory?  It's not clear what is the nature of the queries, but you can create some in memory binary search trees to perform them.

Comment: @wdosanjos I'm simply doing OR read queries. " you can create some in memory binary search trees to perform them" What do you mean?

Comment: I think SQLite is not the right approach for your problem.  Have you looked into [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/)?

Comment: From Wikipedia: [Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree)

Comment: And how exactly are you piping the data?

Comment: @CL. I'm muning it it into csv format, and then creating the table as above

Comment: A CREATE TABLE statement creates an *empty* table. How do you put the data into it?

Comment: @CL. I'm doing this in R, so I use this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/RSQLite.pdf

Comment: Can you please show the R code?

Comment: Are you using [`read.csv.sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332976/how-to-import-csv-into-sqlite-using-rsqlite)?  You may want to create the table with R and then close R and [use the sqlite3 command line shell to import the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r/1820610#1820610).  I would not create any indexes on your table when you're creating it.  Wait until you've imported all your data to do that.

Comment: Also, you may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r/1820610#1820610) generally useful given what you're attempting.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627235/sqlite-import-tab-file-is-import-doing-one-insert-per-row-or-grouping-them-wit) is a decent question showing how to import CSVs into SQLite with the SQLite command shell.  Note that the pragma settings, particularly synchronous, should only be set that way during the import.  They should be re-tuned afterwards to better suit optimizing your reads.