# Add lots of data to SQLite Database in C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I'm currently trying to add a lot of data to a SQLite database in my Windows 8 App using C# and System.Data.SQLite. I have all the objects (MediaItem) in a list and I'm adding each one to the database using a foreach-loop. Unfortunatley this is pretty slow, so I'm wondering if there's a way to speed things up. Can I for example hand over the complete list to the database?
Here's my code so far:

```
List<MediaItem> items;

// adding lots of onbjects to the list...

using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{
     foreach (var item in items)
     {
         db.Insert(item);
     }
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1579201/62576 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/364017/62576 might provide some insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my experience, wrapping as many database calls as possible into a transaction speeds things up quite a bit:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{
    db.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            db.Insert(item);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks so much. Adding 50.000 items now is done in less than a second when earlier it took minutes.