# How to use sqlite bulk insert with windows 8 application?

Tags: windows-8, sqlite, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to use sqlite bulk insert with windows 8 application.. right now I am inserting one row at a time and it takes huge amount of time when working with lots and lots of rows. Can any one help me with this?

Rohit

Comment: If you don't show us your code, we won't be able to tell you that didn't use a single transaction for all inserts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add lots of data to SQLite Database in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671600/add-lots-of-data-to-sqlite-database-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `InsertAll(...)` or `InsertAllAsync(...)` method which takes `IEnumerable<T>` (`List<T>`, `ObservableCollection<T>`, etc) as parameter.

Comment: the InsertAll implementation of Sqlite-Net is actually just doing a forloop on Insert and not using the sqlite "bulk" insert so I don't think you will get much perf improvement ...

Comment: right now I am looping through all the records and inserting it one by one in the db, if InsertAll is doing the same internally then I'll use mine implementation.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Post your implementation also.