# How do I use the SQLite3 import command using the C API?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
int rc;
rc = sqlite3_exec(sqlite3_database, ".import mydata.csv mytable", callback, 0, &errMsg);
```

After this gets run, errMsg contains this error message:

```
near ".": syntax error
```

I assume that it does not recognize the import command. However, this command works when running it from the sqlite3 program on the command line.

I need to be able to use the import command directly in my program. Is there a way I can do this? The reason I need to use the import command is because doing inserts for each line of the CSV file takes over 5 minutes, and the import command takes a split second.

Comment: Here's a related question and subsequent answers on SO (though not iPhone specific): [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364017/faster-bulk-inserts-in-sqlite3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364017/faster-bulk-inserts-in-sqlite3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.import is a part of the command line program interface and not the C API I believe. You can (as i have done) set up all your data in a SQLite3 database file using another tool and then include that database file in your app. Then when you open it in your code, the data is already there.

Comment: The prpogram starts out using a preloaded sqlite3 database file. Problem is I am trying to make an update feature and the CSV file is part of downloadable update to the program.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. I haven't dealt with this yet in my code, but when I do I was considering downloading the CSV update and running the actual update one line at a time from another thread.

Comment: I ended up generating a SQLite database from the server using PHP. 

If I manually do prepared statements and insert each row, it still takes a long time, even on a fast server.

But, using PHP's proc_open command I was able to interface with sqlite3 and use the ".import" command. By doing this the file is generated in a split second, and I simply output the file over HTTP and save it in the iPhone's application writeable directory, and my application is able to use the file without a problem.

Comment: kudos for finding a good solutions and being community minded enough to post it back here. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The command-line shell's `.import` is not part of the C API; the `sqlite3` tool implements it as

```
sqlite3_prepare(..., "INSERT INTO '...' VALUES (?, ..., ?)", ...);
sqlite3_exec(..., "BEGIN", ...);
for (each entry) {
    for (each column) sqlite3_bind_text(..., column, ...);
    sqlite3_step(...);
}
sqlite3_exec(..., "COMMIT", ...);
```

with some error-checking (`ROLLBACK` if anything goes wrong) and handling the prepared statement (`sqlite3_reset`, `sqlite3_finalize`).

Answer (score 3):

Being a quite old post, I just wanted to update for reference only.

There is an open source API I am maintaining for SQLite3 C/C++ API import/export functionality. The code can be accessed via [this link](https://github.com/fnoyanisi)

Comment: It's unclear what you are referring to, can you name it? I don't see any obvious code related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the insert is taking so long because you're having SQLite reparse your INSERT statement for each row (that is, using [**sqlite3_exec()**](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)) rather than using a parameterized prepared statement (that is, using [**sqlite3_prepare_v2()**](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), [**sqlite_bind_*()**](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) and [**sqlite3_step()**](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)).  As ephemient said above, that's how import is implemented internally.

Using a parameterized statement should achieve the same performance as .import, I believe.

Comment: I was using those commands, also sqlite3_reset and sqlite3_finalize. They work but takes 55 seconds using the iPhone Simulator, but over 5 minutes on the actual iPhone.

Comment: @David Barnes:  Was sqlite3_prepare_v2() inside or outside the loop over your file contents?  It should be outside, with bind()/step() inside the loop.