# How to Speed up Insertion of large amount of data in Sqlite

Tags: android, json, loops, parsing

Hello In our app we are inserting large amount of data in database using for loop, First we syncdown our application and getting large json and after parsing we use loop to insert data in separate columns that takes almost 1-2 minutes, I want to make it more faster, I have searched on stackoverflow and found to add transaction [insert a lot of data into sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617524/insert-a-lot-of-data-into-sqlite-in-android) its effective But I want to make it more faster

Here is how we are inserting data

```
return Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe { e: ObservableEmitter<Float?> ->
            db?.beginTransaction()
            clearTable()
            for (i in list.indices) {
                val data = list[i]
                addRecord(data)
                val done = i + 1
                e.onNext(done.toFloat())
            }
            db?.setTransactionSuccessful()
            db?.endTransaction()
            e.onComplete()
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }


    fun addRecord(data: TargetBrands?): Long {
        var id: Long = -1
        try {
            id = targetBrandsDao.insertOrReplace(data)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            CustomMethods.catchException(context, TAG, ex, "addRecord()")
        }
        return id
    }
```

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2) might helps.

Comment: Use this https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmadKhan Currently I am already using transations and Room database ,  already speeds up but I want to improve more speed

Comment: @bakhtiyarhussain, have you checked link in details? As it has many approaches to improve.