# How to write proper big data loader to sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I`m trying to write loader to sqlite that will load as fast as possible simple rows in DB.
Input data looks like rows retrieved from postgres DB. Approximated amount of rows that will go to sqlite: from 20mil to 100mil.
I cannot use other DB except sqlite due to project restrictions.

My question is :
**what is a proper logic to write such loader?**

**At first try** I`ve tried to write set of encapsulated generators, that will take one row from Postgres, slightly ammend it and put it into sqlite. I ended up with the fact that for each row, i create separate sqlite connection and cursor. And that looks awfull.

**At second try** , i moved sqlite connection and cursor out of the generator , to the body of the script  and it became clear that i do not commit data to sqlite untill i fetch and process all 20mils records. And this possibly could crash all my hardware.

**At third try** I strated to consider to keep Sqlite connection away from the loops , but create/close cursor each time i process  and push one row to Sqlite. This is better but i think also have some overhead.

I also considered to play with transactions : One connection, one cursor, one transaction and commit called  in generator each time row is being pushed to Sqlite. Is this i right way i`m going?

Is there some widely-used pattern to write such a component in python? Because I feel as if I am inventing a bicycle.

Comment: Connect once, perform the maximum amount of work in one transaction, and then commit.  Performance will depend on the number of indexes on the target table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i managed to resolve my problem. Main issue was in exessive amount of insertions in sqlite. After i started to load all data from postgress to memory, aggregate it proper way to reduce amount of rows,  i was able to  decrease processing time from  60 hrs to 16 hrs.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite can handle huge transactions with ease, so why *not* commit at the end? Have you tried this at all?

If you do feel one transaction is a problem, why not commit ever `n` transactions? Process rows one by one, insert as needed, but every `n` executed insertions add a `connection.commit()` to spread the load.

Comment: "Second try " approach process 1206072 rows only for 8 hours. it is too slow. I have a perl script , that do something like 100mil rows for less than a 24 hours. However it not inserts them into sqlite, only store in memory, that is why i consider sqlite part a bottleneck. I need to do it as perl or faster if possible. I have near 48 hours max to make a data fetch.

Comment: @Daniel: Committing data to a database with indexes is *always* going to be slower than in-memory ops.

Comment: 2 Martijn   Any thoughts how much slower should i expect? Like 2 (3 or 4 times) slower to sqlite than to memory ?  I want to have approx picture .

Comment: @Daniel: that depends entirely on the indexes, table layouts, size of the rows, etc. Do some tests with subsets of the data and extrapolate.

Comment: 2 Martijn . Thanks. Finally the most heavy bottleneck was in insertion in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

1. [See my previous answer about bulk and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752193/fastest-and-most-efficient-way-to-pre-populate-database-in-android/8855122#8855122). [Possibly my answer here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834553/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-parse-a-json-string-into-an-sqlite-table/10838577#10838577).
2. A question: Do you control the SQLite database? There are [compile time options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) you can tweak related to cache sizes, etc. you can adjust for your purposes as well.

In general, the steps in #1 are going to get you the biggest bang-for-your-buck.