# Most Efficient SQL to Upload CSV to Android SQLite Database

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I've got a CSV file in my `res/raw` directory that I need to upload to an SQLite database in Android. Several other related questions, but my question pertains mostly to the SQL.

[Fastest and most efficient way to pre-populate database in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752193/fastest-and-most-efficient-way-to-pre-populate-database-in-android) they wrap the transaction in `beginTransaction` and `endTransaction` or BEGIN;...COMMIT;. My question is about what comes in between.

In the referenced question, they use `INSERT INTO [table] ([columns]) VALUES ([values]);` for each row in the CSV file. I've grown up on Postgres where you can upload multiple rows in the same SQL statement. Apparently you can do that in SQLite as well according to [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database).

```
INSERT INTO 'tablename'
  SELECT 'data1' AS 'column1', 'data2' AS 'column2'
UNION SELECT 'data3', 'data4'
UNION SELECT 'data5', 'data6'
UNION SELECT 'data7', 'data8'
```

Wrapping within one transaction is a given. Question is, is there a major performance difference between the two SQL statements above??

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on your hardware and your configuration. In any case, the difference will not be major.