# Can one run the sqlite .import command from within JDBC?

Tags: java, performance, sqlite, jdbc, import

Trying it gave me a syntax error on the ".".

If not, is there another way of bulk loading data into a sqlite database with similar performance? .import (from the command line) does in under a minute what inserts (wrapped in a transaction) do in over 20 minutes.

I tried using .import after reading [Faster bulk inserts in sqlite3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364017/faster-bulk-inserts-in-sqlite3). I've tried all the other suggestions there except for virtual tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `.blah` commands are features of the sqlite shell only; they can't be used from JDBC (or any other language embedding either). With a very large data import, it's OK to just run it separately (or in a subprocess, provided the parent is not processing any other transactions at the time).