# transaction management in sqlite3 using expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite

Please guide me how to perform transaction management in sqlite3 using expressjs. I tried in this way but am not succeed.

```
app.get('/transaction', function(req, res){
db.serialize(function() {

    try{
        db.run("BEGIN");
        db.run("UPDATE emp SET balance = 10000 WHERE eid = 1", function(err, row){
            if (err){
                throw (e);
            }
        });
        db.run("UPDATE temp SET deptno = 2000 WHERE eid = 2", function(err, row){
            //this temp table not exists it should be rollback and server should not 
            //stop
            if (err){
                throw (e);
            }
        });

        db.run('commit');
        res.end("Transaction succeed");

    }//try
    catch(e){
        //console.log(e);
        res.end("Transaction cancelled");
        db.run('rollback');
        //console.log(e);
    }//catch
});
```

});

Comment: Can you add what exactly is the error you're facing ?

Comment: it showing e is not found

Comment: I solved in another way. thank You for your kind attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get('/transaction', function(req, res){
db.serialize(function() {  

db.run("BEGIN");

db.run("UPDATE emp SET deptno = 10 WHERE eid = 1", function(err, row){

    if (err){

       console.log(err); 
       res.end("Transaction cancelled"); 

    }

    else{

     db.run("UPDATE temp SET deptno = 20 WHERE eid = 2", function(err, row){

           if (err){

              console.log(err); 

              db.rollback;

              res.end("Transaction cancelled");

             }

          else{

              db.run('commit');

              res.end("Transaction succeed");

              }

         });

        } 

   });
 });
});
```